# Segmentation Fault when calling class functions in async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

I am a beginner at c++ and was messing around with dynamic memory and asynchronous functions and I was not sure why the following code did not work.

What I wanted to do is to basically dynamically create an object of `Loop` and an async function which calls the `start` method of the object, each assigning to a different map variable with the same id as key for both (`randomthing` in the example code).

Expected: print out numbers 10 to 1 every second.

Result: Segmentation Fault

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

class Loop{
    public:
    Loop(int t_):t(t_){}
    void start(){
        while(t>0){
            std::cout << t << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            t--;
        }
    }
    
    private:
    int t;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::future<void>> store;
    std::map<std::string, Loop*> storeClass;
    storeClass["randomthing"] = new Loop(10);
    store["randomthing"] = std::async(std::launch::async, [&storeClass](){
        std::cout << "starting" << std::endl;
        storeClass["randomthing"]->start(); 
        std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
        delete storeClass["randomthing"];
    });
    return 0;
}
```

I messed around it a bit more and found that this modification works:

Declaring store as `std::future<void> store` instead of a map and directly assigning the async function to it after creating the Loop object.

Why the example code does not work and why can the modification fix the issue?

I am compiling the program with -std=c++11.

Comment: So when do you think `storeClass` destructor is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that *all* variables are valid within the lifetime when they are used. Your code:

```
    std::async(std::launch::async, [&storeClass](){
        storeClass["randomthing"]->start(); // uses storeClass
    });
    return 0;
} // calls storeClass destructor
```

Has a race condition, where `storeClass` destructor and use of `storeClass` are unsequenced. In result, when destructor happens to be called after async, then it's fine, otherwise you can get a seg fault.

Do not use raw pointers - use `std::unique_ptr` for `Loop*`.

To solve it you could make `storeClass` a `std::shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` and copy/move it into the lambda run in `async`. Or just wait for the async to complete:

```
    store["randomthing"] = std::async(std::launch::async, [&storeClass](){
         .. use storeClass ..
    });
    store["randomthing"].wait(); // wait for calling `storeClass["randomthing"]
    return 0; 
} // will destroy storeClass
```

Comment: I see. I completely missed the destructor part. But what about the modification? It doesn't seem to fix any of the problems but somehow worked.

Comment: `when destructor happens to be called after async, then it's fine, otherwise you can get a seg fault.`

Comment: So it somehow delayed the call to destructor you mean. Just as a side question, if I understood destructors correctly, they should be called automatically when object's are not used anymore? But in this case, it reaches return 0 randomly in time because of the async so the object will be destroyed at random?

Comment: _Asynchronous_ is a _very hard_ programming concept. Make sure you research it a lot. `they should be called automatically when object's are not used anymore?` An object destructor is called when the lifetime of an object ends, in this case on the end of scope `}` for the object. `But in this case, it would be called randomly?` The call to the destructor and use of the object is _unsequenced_ with each other and moreover is executed in parallel. It may be "random", it may be that a code modification does something.